# Cmake shared library - include doesn't exist

Tags: c++, cmake, include, shared-libraries

I am trying to write a cmake file to create a shared library and use it in the executable file in my project. In the main I include heades as `<pattern_follower/header_file_name.h>`, but when I run make install it says pattern_follower/header_file_name.h does not exist.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(pattern_follower)

add_definitions(-std=c++14)
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*)
file(GLOB HEADERS include/*)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall -O4 -march=native -Wfatal-errors")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}-main main.cpp)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}-main PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME}-main ${PROJECT_NAME})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}-main DESTINATION bin)
install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Does `pattern_follower/header_file_name.h` exist?

Comment: `install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME})` Are your header files in `pattern_follower/include/pattern_follower`??

Comment: I have them in include folder (changed DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME} to DIRECTORY include in CMake) and after installaion I expect them to be in /usr/local/include/pattern_follower/include, but installation fails

Comment: ***but installation fails*** Are you doing the install as root?

Comment: Sure. After I run `sudo make install`, I get `In file included from /home/michail/pattern_follower/main.cpp:1:0:
/home/michail/pattern_follower/include/includes.h:20:49: fatal error: pattern_follower/camera_calibration.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I think you will have to rearrange your folder so that your includes are in `/home/michail/pattern_follower/include/pattern_follower` the problem is a catch22. The install target will not run (copying your includes) until your project is successfully built. Your project won't build until `pattern_follower/camera_calibration.h` exists into one of your include folders (which it does not).

Comment: Thank you for your help!